# Get an array of many objects associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, globalize3, globalize

I didn't know exactly how to find an understandable title so I'll try my best to explain my problem.

I have 2 models:
- Country translatable with globalize, with a name and many regions
- Region belongs_to country

What I would like to do is geting an array of all regions form an array of countries.

E.g.

```
Country.all.regions
Country.with_translations(I18n.locale).order("country_translations.name asc").regions
```

There is an easy way to get this array ?

Comment: Country.all.map {|country| country.regions }.flatten

Comment: Thank you its exactly what I was looking for. I answered with your answer for others !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The @Octopus-Paul solution works, but it has n+1 queries problem. To avoid it, use the `includes` method.

```
Country.includes(:regions).all.map {|country| country.regions }.flatten
```

Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: One nice trick you can do here is use `.flat_map{ ... }` instead of `.map{ ... }.flatten`.

Comment: Another thing you can do to clean it up is: `Country.includes(:regions).all.flat_map(&:regions)`

Answer (score 0):

From @Octopus-Paul:

```
Country.all.map {|country| country.regions }.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search for the regions that match your list of countries:

```
countries = Country.all
regions = Region.where(country: countries)
```

Comment: I know this is pretty explicit, but try to add a bit more text to explain why your solution is the good one